# How to call a View in another folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building my first Asp.net core webservice, that will host a bunch of API's but also must provide a few webpages.

In my home controller I have this code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Info()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult AppMessages()
        {
            return View();
        }
        and so on....
```

This all works well, except fot the last one `AppMessages` and this is because I would like to have this one in a seperate folder, like this

[image]

If I move the file `AppMessages.cshtml` into the folder `Views/Home` then it works, but I would like to put this one in a seperate folder because I got a few more to do and I would like to keep them apart from my other Home pages.

How can I do this ?

EDIT

I also tried with putting the folder `VLA` under the folder `Home` but it did not help

I always get this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'AppMessages' was not found. The
> following locations were searched: /Views/Home/AppMessages.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/AppMessages.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable
> originalLocations)
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'AppMessages' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Home/AppMessages.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/AppMessages.cshtml
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable
> originalLocations)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
> Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
> bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```cs
return View("Views/VLA/AppMessages.cshtml");
```

or

```cs
return View("../VLA/AppMessages");
```

[View discovery documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-discovery)

Comment: That is easy enough, thank you